# How do I get the number of items in a list?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have a list with a lot of items in it I need to know the list item count the following is my code:

```
var sListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var oWeb = item_clientContext.get_web();
var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getById(sListId);
var count = ???
```

How can I determine the count of items I have? I tried get_count() but did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using the JavaScript CSOM you need to fetch the properties asynchronously. Your code should look something like this:

```
var oList;
function theFunction() {
    var sListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var oWeb = item_clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWeb.get_lists().getById(sListId);

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    item_clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
    item_clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    // method will exit here and onSuccess or OnFail will be called asynchronously
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

GL

Answer (score 1):

See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.itemcount.aspx

oList.ItemCount has your property.

Comment: Hi this is javascript, not server side.

Comment: The error is that it is telling me that the list is not initialized. so i tried the following before executing     var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getById(sListId);
    item_clientContext.load(oList);
    item_clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
    var count = oList.get_itemCount();

Comment: still with problem of not initialized

Comment: @IanCian: So `oList` is null? Did you try `var count = oList.ItemCount;`?

Comment: oList will be initialized in onSuccess callback