# count items in a list javascript CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, object-model

I am wanting to count the number of items in my list. Using CSOM in javascript
I have tried it but my code doesn't work. Where am I going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

list = collList.getByTitle('Urgent Alerts');
var items = list.getItems();
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed))

function Success(sender, args) {
var itemCount = items.get_count();
alert(itemCount);
}

function Failed(sender, args) {
alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85628/using-csom-to-get-list-item-count-for-multiple-lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `context.executeQueryAsync` And then try to get the item count in the success method.

**UPDATE**

You are not specifying the query in `SP.List.getItems(query_);`
Example:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();

list = collList.getByTitle('Urgent Alerts');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed))

function Success(sender, args) {
    var itemCount = items.get_count();
alert(itemCount);
}

function Failed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: So what query should I use?

Comment: I am not querying anything

Comment: If you are not querying anything you need to simply load the list. `list.getItems()` expects a `CamlQuery` object as paramter.

Answer (score 1):

[Use This link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18050/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-items-in-a-list)

```
var oList;
function theFunction() {
    var sListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var oWeb = item_clientContext.get_web();
    oList = oWeb.get_lists().getById(sListId);

    // .load() tells CSOM to load the properties of this object
    // multiple .load()s can be stacked
    item_clientContext.load(oList);

    // now start the asynchronous call and perform all commands
    item_clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    // method will exit here and onSuccess or OnFail will be called asynchronously
}
function onSuccess(sender, args) {
    alert('No of rows: ' + oList.get_itemCount());
}
function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed.\n' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code with this bit :

```
list = collList.getByTitle('Urgent Alerts');
this.items = list.getItems();
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.Success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Failed))


function Success(sender, args) {
    var itemEnumerator= this.items.getEnumerator();
    var itemCOunt = itemEnumerator.$2K_0;
    alert(itemCount);
}
```